JNI project uses backtrace to generate crash stack trace, but it cannot be resolved with addr2line
signal_handler code
void *trace[100];
// Get the stack trace first
int trace_size = ::backtrace(trace, 100);
char** backtrace_strings = backtrace_symbols(trace, trace_size);
if (backtrace_strings) {
    for (int i = 0; i < trace_size; i++) {
        ::write(fd, backtrace_strings[i], strlen(backtrace_strings[i]));
        ::write(fd, "\n", 1);
    }
    free(backtrace_strings);
}

backtrace stack symbol
MyApp crashed by signal: 11
Accessing address: (nil)

------ STACK TRACE ------
EIP:
/tmp/vectorcorenativeutils23241153416458/libvectorcorejni_x86_avx512.so(_Z9trigger_1v+0x65)[0x7fc724784d95]

Backtrace:
/tmp/vectorcorenativeutils23241153416458/libvectorcorejni_x86_avx512.so(_Z16writeStackTrace2iPvi+0x89) [0x7fc7247849b9]
/tmp/vectorcorenativeutils23241153416458/libvectorcorejni_x86_avx512.so(_Z14sigsegvHandleriP9siginfo_tPv+0xc4) [0x7fc724784b04]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf6d0) [0x7fc7a68a76d0]
/tmp/vectorcorenativeutils23241153416458/libvectorcorejni_x86_avx512.so(_Z9trigger_1v+0x65) [0x7fc724784d95]
/tmp/vectorcorenativeutils23241153416458/libvectorcorejni_x86_avx512.so(_ZNK7lindorm6vector9FlatIndex11getDistanceEPKvRKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaISA_EEifRSt5dequeISt4pairIfSA_ESaISH_EE+0xd90) [0x7fc724786cb0]
/tmp/vectorcorenativeutils23241153416458/libvectorcorejni_x86_avx512.so(Java_com_alibaba_lindorm_base_vectorcore_FlatIndex_getDistance+0x126) [0x7fc724763386]
[0x7fc7881cea10]

addr2line failed
addr2line -e /tmp/vectorcorenativeutils23241153416458/libvectorcorejni_x86_avx512.so -f 0x7fc724784d95
??
??:0

I tried to use addr2line, but it can not resolve the symbol

Unrelated: you can use backtrace_symbols_fd to dump it directly to fd

These addresses are meaningless outside of the current program run because of ASLR. You need to subtract the base address of the library (which you can parse out of /proc/self/maps or a core dump) so you get an offset relative to the file start...
